# How to programmatically access G Suite DLP audit events

Tags: api, sdk, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am exploring G Suite DLP feature. I can view DLP audit events (i.e. policy violations) by clicking on 'Rules' -> 'Audit' from G Suite admin panel but I couldn't find a programatic way to access these events either through the SDK or APIs. Is there a way to consume these events programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there's now way of doing this through API. Atleast, none mentioned in [Scan and protect Drive files using DLP rules](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6321530?hl=en). You'll have to keep an eye peeled for future updates.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017-08-22 you can query rule matches via the reports API:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/rules